# best way to externalize HTML in GWT apps?

Tags: java, html, gwt

What's the best way to **externalize large quantities of HTML** in a GWT app?  We have a rather complicated GWT app of about 30 "pages"; each page has a sort of guide at the bottom that is  several paragraphs of HTML markup.  I'd like to externalize the HTML so that it can remain as "unescaped" as possible.

I know and understand how to use **property files** in GWT; that's certainly better than embedding the content in Java classes, but still kind of ugly for HTML (you need to backslashify everything, as well as escape quotes, etc.)

**Normally this is the kind of thing you would put in a JSP**, but I don't see any equivalent to that in GWT.  I'm considering just writing a widget that will simply fetch the content from html files on the server and then add the text to an HTML widget.  But it seems there ought to be a simpler way.

Comment: It sounds to me that you simply are using GWT the wrong way. There shouldn't be "large quantities of HTML" in a GWT app. I worked in one with *hundreds* of GWT screens, and we had virtually no HTML markup at all (either in Java code or in GWT host pages). The actual HTML was produced dynamically by the JavaScript code generated from Java code by the GWT compiler - this is the whole point of GWT, after all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use some templating mechanism. Try [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/) or [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) templates. You'll be having your HTML in files that will be retrieved by templating libraries. These files can be named with proper extensions, e.g. .html, .css, .js obsearvable on their own.

Comment: Because the whole point of GWT is to write clientside apps. There is no need to go to the server to fetch this html. In a lesser environment one would use an iframe etc. but GWT lets you generate different js sensitive to your locale with strings containing html resources etc. The answer is Client Bundles as mentioned below.

Comment: While FreeMarker and Velocity are great tools for working on the server-side, I don’t think it would be a good solution within a GWT client-side environment. GWT imposes restrictions on the Java code that can execute on the client, and traditional templating libraries like the ones you’ve mentioned wouldn’t run.

Answer (score 22):

I've used ClientBundle in a similar setting. I've created a package my.resources and put my HTML document and the following class there:

```
package my.resources;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle;
import com.google.gwt.resources.client.TextResource;

public interface MyHtmlResources extends ClientBundle {
 public static final MyHtmlResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(MyHtmlResources.class);

 @Source("intro.html")
 public TextResource getIntroHtml();

}
```

Then I get the content of that file by calling the following from my GWT client code:

```
HTML htmlPanel = new HTML();
String html = MyHtmlResources.INSTANCE.getIntroHtml().getText();
htmlPanel.setHTML(html);
```

See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html for further information.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks, @Futzilogik!  However, for some reason, the scripts inside my "intro.html" don't run, even if it's a simple `<script>alert("Hi!");</script>`.  Any reason you can think of that that shouldn't work?

Answer (score 5):

I'd say you load the external html through a [Frame](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html).

```
Frame frame = new Frame();
frame.setUrl(GWT.getModuleBase() + getCurrentPageHelp());
add(frame);
```

You can arrange some convention or lookup for the *getCurrentPageHelp(*) to return the appropriate path (eg: */manuals/myPage/help.html*)

Here's an [example](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Panels~Frame) of frame in action.

Answer (score 5):

In GWT 2.0, you can do this using the [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html).

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'>
  <div>
    Hello, <span ui:field='nameSpan’/>, this is just good ‘ol HTML.
  </div>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

These files are kept separate from your Java code and can be edited as HTML. They are also provide integration with GWT widgets, so that you can easily access elements within the HTML from your GWT code.

Answer (score 3):

GWT 2.0, when released, should have a ClientBundle, which probably tackles this need.

Answer (score 1):

You could try implementing a `Generator` to load external HTML from a file at compile time and build a class that emits it. There doesn't seem to be too much help online for creating generators but here's a post to the GWT group that might get you started: [GWT group on groups.google.com](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/msg/ae249ea67c2c3435).

Answer (score 1):

I was doing similar research and, so far, I see that the best way to approach this problem is via the [DeclarativeUI or UriBind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766149/is-it-possible-to-separate-totally-the-html-css-layout-from-the-gwt-logic/772793#772793).  Unfortunately it still in incubator, so we need to work around the problem.

I solve it in couple of different ways:

1. Active overlay, i.e.: you create your standard HTML/CSS and inject the GET code via `<script>` tag. Everywhere you need to access an element from GWT code you write something like this:

   ```
   RootPanel.get("element-name").setVisible(false);
   ```
2. You write your code 100% GWT and then, if a big HTML chunk is needed, you bring it to the client either via IFRAME or via AJAX and then inject it via HTML panel like this:

   ```
   String html = "<div id='one' "
      + "style='border:3px dotted blue;'>"
      + "</div><div id='two' "
      + "style='border:3px dotted green;'"
      + "></div>";
   HTMLPanel panel = new HTMLPanel(html);
   panel.setSize("200px", "120px");
   panel.addStyleName("demo-panel");
   panel.add(new Button("Do Nothing"), "one");
   panel.add(new TextBox(), "two");
   RootPanel.get("demo").add(panel);
   ```

Comment: The issue isn't what widget to use for HTML data; the issue is how to get the HTML *out* of the code, and into something more natural like a .html file.

Comment: Yep. The example above is not to show how to put the HTML into the code, but merely to show that you can reference HTML that is residing outside of your code that can be packaged in multiple ways. In the example above it was a string. In the same way you can reference the external files via URL.

Comment: Put the HTML into a file (*.html if you want), load the file on the server and use the HTMLPanel() to display the content.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use good-old IFRAME? Just create an iFrame where you wish to put a hint and change its location when GWT 'page' changes.

Advantages:

- Hits are stored in separate maintainable HTML files of any structure
- AJAX-style loading with **no coding at all** on server side
- If needed, application could still interact with loaded info

Disadvantages:

- Each hint file should have link to shared CSS for common look-and-feel
- Hard to internationalize

To make this approach a bit better, you might handle loading errors and redirect to default language/topic on 404 errors. So, search priority will be like that:

1. Current topic for current language
2. Current topic for default language
3. Default topic for current language
4. Default error page

I think it's quite easy to create such GWT component to incorporate iFrame interactions

Comment: So, you might have such file structure on your server:
/help/welcome/en.html or /help/welcome-en.html

this page will contain english text for topic or GWT-page 'welcome'

Comment: Because GWT supports creating classses with getters that include html with parameters from html files. It also supports fetching generating different permutations of your program each with different html based on a locale. If you thought of it, its been done better in GWT.

Answer (score 1):

The GWT Portlets framework (http://code.google.com/p/gwtportlets/) includes a WebAppContentPortlet. This serves up any content from your web app (static HTML, JSPs etc.). You can put it on a page with additional functionality in other Portlets and everything is fetched with a single async call when the page loads.

Have a look at the source for WebAppContentPortlet and WebAppContentDataProvider to see how it is done or try using the framework itself. Here are the relevant bits of source:

WebAppContentPortlet (client side)

```
((HasHTML)getWidget()).setHTML(html == null ? "<i>Web App Content</i>" : html);
```

WebAppContentDataProvider (server side):

```
HttpServletRequest servletRequest = req.getServletRequest();
String path = f.path.startsWith("/") ? f.path : "/" + f.path;
RequestDispatcher rd = servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(path);
BufferedResponse res = new BufferedResponse(req.getServletResponse());
try {
   rd.include(servletRequest, res);
   res.getWriter().flush();
   f.html = new String(res.toByteArray(), res.getCharacterEncoding());
} catch (Exception e) {
   log.error("Error including '" + path + "': " + e, e);
   f.html = "Error including '" + path +
        "'<br>(see server log for details)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use servlets with jsps for the html parts of the page and still include the javascript needed to run the gwt app on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I'm going to assume you've factored out this common summary into it's own widget. If so, the problem is that you don't like the ugly way of embedding HTML into the Java code.

GWT 2.0 has **UiBinder**, which allows you to define the GUI in raw HTMLish template, and you can inject values into the template from the Java world. Read through the [dev guide](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) and it gives a pretty good outline.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [GWT App](http://www.gwtapp.org/) with html templates generated and binded on run-time, no compiling-time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 
http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html

Answer (score -2):

Not knowing GWT, but can't you define and anchor div tag in your app html then perform a get against the HTML files that you need, and append to the div?  How different would this be from a [micro-template](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)?

UPDATE:

I just found this nice jQuery plugin in an answer to another [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365699/better-way-or-reusable-code-to-populate-an-html-element-or-create-a-select-after) question.

Comment: The questioner wishes to avoid the round trip to fetch the html. Basically they want to embed the escaped pages as a String within the app automatically aka using ClientBundle.