# Load HTML document to populate HTMLPanel a good idea?

Tags: gwt

I want to load "pieces" of HTML to set HTMLPanels which will be dynamically modified by getting the id's as follows:

```
HTMLPanel dynContent = new HTMLPanel("<div id=\"test_id\"/>");
dynContent.add(new Label("This content is dynamically generated."), "test_id");
```

Can I serve HTML files to my client from a GWT app (It would be cool to just load the html files served at application startup)? Or do I have to create a call to the server to get the HTML (say RPC)? It sounds like JSP is the solution but I rather stay away from this for such a simple app.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: now that I think about it, I would need to get the css to :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is pretty neat! I first found this:
[best way to externalize HTML in GWT apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744137/best-way-to-externalize-html-in-gwt-apps)

Then tried this to load static data via Client Bundle:

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
    Resources INSTANCE = GWT.create(Resources.class);

    @Source("public/html/timesheet.html")
    TextResource synchronous();

}
```

Then I load the resources in my html panel:

```
 HTMLPanel dynContent = new HTMLPanel(Resources.INSTANCE.synchronous().getText());
 dynContent.add(new Label("This content is dynamically generated."), "dynContent");

 simplePanel.add(dynContent);
```

The content from the HTML file I have is fetched and populates the HTMLPanel as I wanted.