# How GWT could do some live rendering of HTML?

Tags: html, gwt

The whole html package is such as:

```
/css
/EARoot
/files
/images
/js
blank.html
index.html
toc.html
```

We are trying to open "index.html" from directory run time, and then display the main page of this HTML. Then could do live rendering of HTML and switch the page by clicking the button/link in the html page, etc.

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a Hello World case.
http://www.gwtproject.org/gettingstarted.html

Comment: Thanks! Might be more complicated than it.

Comment: If the html page is available in your client then use native script else, make a service call to the server part and get the html and load it in the main page

Comment: The html files will be dynamically, not-static, allow the user open index.htm, then could display the home html page, then could change pages like IE browser display html files and navigation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your HTML pages are dynamic, then use RPC call to invoke a servlet and then get your dynamic html page and load it.

If your HTML pages are static use ClientBundle to load the static html pages

References:

[Making GWT Remote Procedure Calls](https://dzone.com/articles/making-gwt-remote-procedure-ca)

[Load HTML document to populate HTMLPanel a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837633/load-html-document-to-populate-htmlpanel-a-good-idea)

[best way to externalize HTML in GWT apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744137/best-way-to-externalize-html-in-gwt-apps)

Comment: My case is dynamically, any user could open  "whole html files folder" stored in his local side, , for example, when he load "index.htm" to the "GWT", somehow GWT could display the index page in "GWT Frame/HTML Panel, etc" , then user could click element (mark up) in current page to go to other page, just like normal browser. job....   Should load whole html folder including "js" to server through RPC?  How GWT handle many related html pages ? Which directory store these html/js  ?   Thanks!