# jquery load() equivalent in GWT

Tags: gwt

I wonder if there is an equivalent load() of jQuery in GWT without using frames or any GWT framework.

I need to load a file .html in a div with GWT.

Something like this: RootPanel.get("content").add(page.html);

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Add this: `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.http.HTTP" />`
to your gwt.xml file

Then you can do something with the `HTML` widget and the RequestBuilder

For example

```
import com.google.gwt.http.client.*;
...
HTML htmlWidget = null;
String url = "http://www.myserver.com/getData?type=3";
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(url));

try {
  Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {

    }

    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
      if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
         htmlWidget = new HTML(response.getText());
      } else {
        // Handle the error.  Can get the status text from response.getStatusText()
      }
  }       
 });
} catch (RequestException e) {
  // Couldn't connect to server        
}
if(htmlWidget!=null){
    RootPanel.get("content").add(htmlWidget);
}
```

I could not see if it compiles (no access to an IDE at the moment) so excuse any minor errors you might need to correct.

Comment: I am guessing something went missing in "Add this" . Some link?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches documented here [best way to externalize HTML in GWT apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744137/best-way-to-externalize-html-in-gwt-apps)

I would prefer client bundle with a html resource in your scenario.