# load html pages on client side on button click

Tags: html, gwt

I am new to GWT. How do i load different and static HTML pages on the client side via button clicks. Have read up and do not wish to go into RPC, frames, client bundles and the following page:

[best way to externalize HTML in GWT apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744137/best-way-to-externalize-html-in-gwt-apps)

If client bundles are the closest i can get, may I have a very simple example, assuming that i have 4 HTML pages to be loaded on the client side, navigable by button clicks?

From my understanding, these individual pages may be created by UIBinders - please correct me if I'm wrong.

I have only the following code to display another page upon click, which is not working the way I want it. Also it gives a 403 error:

```
button.addClickHandler (new ClickHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onClick (ClickEvent event){
                //Window.alert("Hello again");

                String winUrl = GWT.getModuleBaseURL();
                String winName = "Testing Window";

                openNewWindow (winName, winUrl);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the state of your browser client page, then something like:

```
Window.Location.replace(newUrl);
```

Then the html page you point to in `newUrl` may or may not load the same java script as the current page.

If you do care about keeping the state of your browser client page and just want to avoid loading your static page at initial load time (by default all your pages get loaded at once), then [code splitting](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html) is your friend.  The principle is to wrap the code showing your new page around an async call defining the code split, something like:

```
GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback()
{
  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable reason)
  {
    Window.alert("Error in fetching the split javascript for page ...");
  }
  @Override
  public void onSuccess()
  {
    // Code to setup and show your new static page instead of the current page.
    // This code will be in a javascript file that won't be loaded at initial page load.
    // You must make sure though that the below code does not use/include common code.
    RootPanel.get().clear();
    RootPanel.get().add(newWidget);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is as simple as:

Window.Location.assign("MenuPage.html");